# Call angular function from protractor

Tags: html, angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I'm new to Angular and Protractor.

I'm using protractor to test Angular pages.
I'm trying to test log-in procedure.

part of the html is:

```
< li data-ng-show="isLoggedIn()" >
```

I want to make sure that the credentials are correct by calling the 'isLoggedIn()' function.
the 'isLoggedIn()' function is in a controller named 'navControl'.

can I do it? How?
are there other suggestions to test log-in?

Answer (score 2):

You should be testing your log in page (if you are using protractor) like a user - enter some text in your login form, then click the 'Log In' button! After this, inspect the page for whatever elements you are expecting to be visible after a user has logged in. You shouldn't really be directly calling your application functions - testing those falls under unit testing, not e2e testing for which Protractor is designed for :)

Comment: thanks for answering. the question is how to do it. the < li > element that I have posted is the element that changes when logged in. it turns to 'show'. how can I check it?

Comment: You need to read up on the two things you are using; ng-show will simply add the ng-hide css class to an element when it should be hidden, and will remove the ng-hide css class when the element should be shown. (Taken from the docs, [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow).) Next, in protractor, you want a test that checks to see if your <li> element is shown - to do this you can check to see if it has the css class I mentioned. Examples of how to do this can be found on the Protractor help, [here](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/).

Comment: (continued) - Your test might check for the existence of the class with a line similar to this:
  expect(hasClass(element(by.id('my_list_id')), 'ngHide')).toBe(true);

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for helping.
The exact phrase I was looking for is this:

```
expect($('[data-ng-show="isLoggedIn()"]').isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
```